# Saving a contribution adds a line with negative the tax amount, when using an event price set

Tags: civievent, contributions, price-sets, taxes

I replicated this issue in the demo wordpress account. If one creates a paid event with a financial type that includes taxes, enters a price (without using price sets) and books a person, then opening the contribution and clicking the 'save' button behaves correctly.

The problem appears when the event price is a price set. Each time one opens the corresponding contribution and clicks 'save', a new accounting line is created with negative the amount of taxes.

Example after opening and saving several times:
(the total amount should be 400 SEK, but now it say 14 SEK)

[image]

This happens when the price set is used with an event, but also (at times) when directly creating a contribution with the same price set as above, but without registering to an event.

Comment: My issue seems to be the one in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19966 that is marked as Fixed. I will need to look deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. I'm unsure if price set config for events was previously tested. I've created an issue in JIRA for this https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20676 and we'll work on fixing pro bono (though contributions to help fund fix would be very welcome!).